# Split parts of function calling

Tags: c++

I am going to give the least extreme example I have: (Names/Identifiers are *irrelevant*)

```
session.TransmitUnsafe(
    Details::Solve,
    samplesCount,
    pinnedInputData.GetDevicePointer( ),
    Offset( pinnedOutputApproximationData.GetDevicePointer( ), outputIndex ),
    Offset( SolutionData.get( ), SolutionIndices.at( outputIndex * SolutionSize ) ),
    InputLength,
    OutputLength,
    samplesCount
);
```

I need to split it to something like this:

```
auto kernelCallingHeader = {
    Details::Solve,
    samplesCount
};
auto kernelArgumentsPointers = {
    pinnedInputData.GetDevicePointer( ),
    Offset( pinnedOutputApproximationData.GetDevicePointer( ), outputIndex ),
    Offset( SolutionData.get( ), SolutionIndices.at( outputIndex * SolutionSize ) )
};
auto kernelArgumentsLengths = {
    InputLength,
    OutputLength,
    samplesCount
};

session.TransmitUnsafe(
    kernelCallingHeader...,
    kernelArguments...,
    kernelArgumentsLengths...
);
```

I can't change `session.TransmitUnsafe`'s parameters at all, but I want to somehow `struct`ize the calling to that function. (Entirely for readability purposes)

NOTE: I used `...` like expandation of variadic template function's arguments, because I am sure there's a fine way with it.
It won't harm even to have a few macros.

Comment: just define a forwarding function

Comment: You could just make a function that takes the structs and calls the real function  You can always test and make sure the compiler optimizes it out.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf How and maybe a bit of explanation?

Comment: @xaxxon That's a way... but `session.TransmitUnsafe` is a template, I will have to make templated structs, which their template arguments are not related to the struct. (The structs will look like `KernelCalling<void(*)(const int*,.......)>`, which is ugly.

Comment: It's tough to give suggestions when you change the problem..

Comment: variadic templates/function has nothing to do with your post

Comment: @xaxxon Sorry, I tried to give the question abstract as possible.

Comment: that's fine, but the answers will be equally abstract.  "what dessert should I have with dinner?"  "chocolate cake" "oh, I don't like chocolate"